# Don't receive email notifications from Jenkins if build fail

Tags: email, docker, smtp, jenkins-plugins

I have a problem with notifications from Jenkins. I have Jenkins container and try to build ant application. I want to have email notifications if build is fail. I try to use ext Email notification plugin but in some way id doesn't work. In build console i see this

Package has been validated succesfully!
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: me@mymail.com

But i don't receive any emails. Using console i can send emails from Jenkins container. i am using this comand ssh server@serverip "echo Test email | mailx -S smtp=smtp_address:25 -S from=jenkins@server.com -v me@mymail.com"

Comment: mailx is an external command which is properly configured since it works for you. Jenkins mail service is embedded in Jenkins. Could be a firewall/antivirus policy to authorize only some applications to send e-mails.

Comment: maybe i need to install smtp server into container?

Comment: Beats me, I'm just giving leads here: not trying to answer definitely. Ask your local IT technician or if you're at home, try whay you said.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending email from _inside_ the container? Looks like you might be sending it from the docker host. I wouldn't set up a smtp server inside the Jenkins container -- that may certainly solve your problem, but could cause others. I would set Jenkins up to use an external (yours or 3rd-party) SMTP service.

Comment: ldg can you tel me how can i set Jenkins to use an external SMPT service from container